# AngularJS and ApiRTC

Tags: webrtc

I am currently trying to use **ApiRTC** ([apirtc](https://apirtc.com/)) with AngularJS and cordova.

I want the callee to "Accept" before the call starts. When the callee accepts, the caller have a different UI.

But whenever I'm trying to reproduce [this example](https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-examples/blob/master/Tutorials/Video_client_Material/apiRTC-Material-Client-Video-AcceptRefuse.html) in my project with *callAudio()* instead of *call()* :

The call is established before the callee can click on a "Accept/Reject".
In other words, the **callEstablished** event is fired to the caller before the callee clicks on the "Accept" button.

When the callee clicks on "Accept", it fires another **callEstablished** event.

I'm using the following instructions in that order

```
apiRTC.init({
  apiCCId : $scope.callData.callerId,
  apiKey : "<MY_API_KEY>",
  onReady: sessionReadyHandler,
  idConversionActivated : false,
});
```

then

```
apiRTC.addEventListener("callEstablished", callEstablishedHandler);
apiRTC.addEventListener("userMediaSuccess", userMediaSuccessHandler);
apiRTC.addEventListener("incomingCall", incomingCallHandler);
apiRTC.addEventListener("userMediaError", userMediaErrorHandler);
apiRTC.addEventListener("hangup", hangupHandler);
apiRTC.addEventListener("remoteStreamAdded", remoteStreamAddedHandler);
apiRTC.addEventListener("connectedUsersListUpdate", connectedUsersListUpdateHandler);
apiRTC.addEventListener("error", function(e) {...});
```

then

```
// webRTC client creation
webRTCClient = apiRTC.session.createWebRTCClient({
});

// Multi calls Activation
webRTCClient.setAllowMultipleCalls(true);

// Bandwitdh limitation
webRTCClient.setVideoBandwidth(300);

// Accept-Refuse
webRTCClient.setUserAcceptOnIncomingCall(true);
```

and finally:

```
webRTCClient.callAudio($scope.callData.receiverId);
```

And only with those instructions, the call is established (event + can listen voice/audio). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by binding the remote stream manually.

- **Caller**: in the **callEstablished** handler
- **Callee**: in my **acceptCall()** function called on user click.

$scope.callState.active = true;
      webRTCClient.acceptCall($scope.callId);

```
  // Add streams
  if ($scope.localStreamEvent && $scope.remoteStreamEvent) {
    console.log("STREAMS:");
    console.log($scope.localStreamEvent.detail.stream.id);
    console.log($scope.remoteStreamEvent.detail.stream.id);

    webRTCClient.addStreamInDiv($scope.remoteStreamEvent.detail.stream, $scope.remoteStreamEvent.detail.callType, 
      "remote", 'remoteElt-' + $scope.remoteStreamEvent.detail.callId,
             {width : "640px", height : "480px"}, false);

    $scope.callState.active = true;
  }
```

**$scope.localStreamEvent** and **$scope.remoteStreamEvent** being filled here:

```
function userMediaSuccessHandler(e) {
    $scope.localStreamEvent = e;

    webRTCClient.addStreamInDiv($scope.localStreamEvent.detail.stream, $scope.localStreamEvent.detail.callType,
          "mini", 'miniElt-' + $scope.localStreamEvent.detail.callId,
          {width : "128px", height : "96px"}, true);

}

function remoteStreamAddedHandler(e) {
  $scope.remoteStreamEvent = e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly setting the following option on your client?

Try this:

```
webRTCClient.setUserAcceptOnIncomingCall(true);
```

Comment: I've added a code description, it it can help to target the problem.